# 'String"does not have a member named 'category

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Here is what I'm trying, basically to query the key "categories" of the class "event" for only the current user:

```
class AllEntriesTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var allEntries = [""]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var user = PFUser.currentUser()

    var query = PFQuery(className:"event")
    query.whereKey("user", equalTo: user)
    query.includeKey("category")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
       (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
       if error == nil {
         // The find succeeded.
         self.allEntries.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

        // Do something with the found objects
         for object in objects {
            var allEnt:String = object as String
            self.allEntries.append(allEnt.category)
         }
       } else {
          // Log details of the failure
          NSLog("Error: %@ %@", error, error.userInfo!)
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're expecting `allEnt` to be a `String` and not an `event`.

```
var allEnt:String = object as String
self.allEntries.append(allEnt.category)
```

You should be creating `allEnt` as `event` vars instead if you are intending to access `allEnt.category` as a property on `event`. Perhaps you have forgotten a lookup of some kind? Something like:

```
convertToEvent(allEnt)
self.keyToEventDictionary[allEnt]
```

Or is it possible that your `objects` list is actually a list of `category` results and you should just be doing:

```
self.allEntries.append(allEnt)
```